# A verb 'biodegrade' as transitive and intransitive

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, transitivity

As you can see from these [examples](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/biodegrade) the verb 'biodegrade' is intransitive (it no longer requires direct object = who is going to biodegrade something)

> I feel like using this verb as 'passive voice structure' like in all these [examples](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=was%20biodegraded)

---

Question:

For me this sentence *(most plastics **will not biodegrade** in landfill sites)* sounds odd, it feels like passive voice should have been used *(most plastics **will not BE biodegradeD** in landfill sites)*, 
but I trust Oxford, is it some kind of exception?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the many questions here tagged [tag:middle-voice], which deal with what are sometimes called *labile* verbs: verbs which are deployed both as transitives, with an Agent carrying out an action on a Patient, and as intransitives, with the Patient cast as the active Subject. Most such verbs, like *biodegrade*, designated changes of state, externally caused in the transitive use and attributed in the intransitive use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of scientific journals, you're more likely to hear *biodegrade* as an intransitive verb:

> Everyone knows those plastic supermarket bags don't **biodegrade**, and end up in our rivers and oceans, but we use them anyway.
>
> The nice thing about this cleanser is that it naturally **biodegrades** in water, so you don't have to worry about problems with the environment.

Also common is the adjective *biodegradable*.

> Even though they are more expensive, the concert concessions stands will use only **biodegradable** cups for beverages.

Comment: Outside of technical contexts, I think *biodegradable* is far more commonly used. "plastic supermarket bags aren't biodegradable" and "is that it is naturally biodegradable in water".

Comment: @user3169  Yes, I agree.